# cant install ubuntu 23.04 alongside win11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install to install Ubuntu 23.04 alongside Windows 11, but the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option is not showing.

I have done the basic steps like:

**Disable secure boot**

fast boot and hibernate settings:

[image: here]

**Create unallocated partition**

[image: here]

Here are the configurations of my laptop:

- Asus Vivobook 15
- 8GB RAM
- 512GB SSD (desired installation drive)
- 1TB HDD

About the Ubuntu ISO:

- desktop
- amd64 (not legacy)

Comment: You've not mentioned what Ubuntu 23.04 product you're trying to install (eg. Server? Desktop?) and if it's Desktop you should also tell us which installer you opted to use (two ISOs are offered when you download Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop for example; which you download dictates what installer you'll use). You won't need to disable secure boot (*in fact I'd leave it the same as whatever your windows is using!*) though who ISO is written does matter. Did you disable fastboot? hibernate? on windows (*not doing that will cause what you describe as the drive maybe ignored*).

Comment: its a ubuntu desktop amd64 iso installer which is flashed to a usb drive using rufus

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the installer? Or simply describe what other options are there

Answer (score 0):

After disabling the secure boot you need to change the boot option from BIOS to your bootable USB. After that follow the instructions from this [article](https://www.xda-developers.com/dual-boot-windows-11-linux/). Hope this helps :)

Comment: i originally followed the very same article                                                                                               step by step

Comment: There must be something you might've missed. I recently switched to Ubuntu no more windows.

Comment: are you using a dual boot or ubuntu only?

Comment: and i did not miss anything

Comment: Ubuntu only. I followed an article from itsfoss

Comment: but i want to install with a dual boot